# Best way to achieve @Autowired @Lazy @Components via annotations?

Tags: java, spring, lazy-loading

Is there a way to have `@Lazy` loading `@Component`s that are still `@Autowired` in a factory via annotations? The problem I found is that by autowiring my lazy components in the factory, they will all be instantiated immediately once the factory is loaded, negating the lazy annotation.

I have defined several lazy beans such as

```
@Component
@Lazy
public final class CloseableChromeWebDriver
      extends ChromeDriver
      implements DisposableBean {
...
}

@Component
@Lazy
public final class CloseableFirefoxWebDriver
      extends FirefoxDriver
      implements DisposableBean {
...
}
```

It is important that they be lazy because

- Whenever one of them is created, the browser window pops up.
- my data driven tests may or may not require any one or all of them i.e. one run may be all Firefox, or may require Firefox and Chrome.
- this is more important because in fact I have six such beans - Firefox, Chrome, IE, Remote Firefox, Remote Chrome, Remote IE.
- So, if my tests only use one of them, then I only want that one browser to show, not all them.

I have a Factory for getting the requested browser, but my first attempt at this failed because whenever any class used the factory, all of the autowired beans were being instantiated straight away, irrespective of whether they were actually requested. I understand this is because once the class is instantiated, it must instantiate all of the instance variables belonging to it.

```
@Component
public final class WebDriverFactory {
   @Autowired
   private CloseableChromeWebDriver chromeWebDriver;
   @Autowired
   private CloseableFirefoxWebDriver firefoxWebDriver;

   public synchronized WebDriver getWebDriver(final Browser browser) {
     // get whatever webdriver is matched by the enum Browser.
   }
}
```

So here is my second approach which is to ensure lazy loading by requesting the bean through the application context:

```
@Component
public final class WebDriverFactory {
   private CloseableChromeWebDriver chromeWebDriver;
   private CloseableFirefoxWebDriver firefoxWebDriver;
   @Autowired
   private ApplicationContext appContext;

   public synchronized WebDriver getWebDriver(final Browser browser) {
      WebDriver driver = null;
      switch (browser) {
         case FIREFOX:
            if (firefoxRemoteWebDriver == null) {
               firefoxRemoteWebDriver = appContext.getBean("closeableRemoteFirefoxWebDriver",
                     CloseableRemoteFirefoxWebDriver.class);
            }
            driver = firefoxRemoteWebDriver;
            break;
      // etc...
      return driver;
   }
}
```

This approach achieves my goal, but I feel it really negates the usefulness of using annotations. Is there a purely annotation based way to achieve this?

- JDK 6
- Spring 3.2.6.RELEASE
- No xml, just annotations.

Comment: Surely the `@Lazy` attribute goes on the user of the bean, not on the definition of the bean. So I'd expect you to put `@Lazy` everywhere that needs that bean to be lazy loaded. If that's EVERYWHERE, then the bean will be created when first used.

Comment: @AshleyFrieze Unless I have misunderstood what you are saying, no `@Lazy` doesn't go on the user of the bean.. From the [@Lazy Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html): _May be used on any class directly or indirectly annotated with @Component or on methods annotated with @Bean.... If present and set to true, the @Bean or @Component will not be initialized until referenced by another bean or explicitly retrieved from the enclosing BeanFactory._

Comment: @AshleyFrieze, in Spring 4, you are actually right, as per Biju's answer.. so thanks. :)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You have to have `@Lazy` annotation on your component as well at the point where it is `@Autowired` in. This is because if you don't have `@Lazy` on your component, then it is eagerly created as a bean, and if you have don't have an `@Lazy` on your `@Autowired` then again it is eagerly created and injected into the bean. So try the following and it should just work:

```
@Component
public final class WebDriverFactory {
   @Autowired @Lazy
   private CloseableChromeWebDriver chromeWebDriver;
   @Autowired @Lazy
   private CloseableFirefoxWebDriver firefoxWebDriver;
```

Comment: I am fairly sure that needs Spring 4, as I was reading about that last night here: http://zezutom.blogspot.com.au/2014/01/spring-series-part-4-lazy-on-injection.html. We are using Spring 3 atm, however that same page seems to explain how to achieve the same effect with Provider. I haven't tried that because frankly I failed to understand it just yet.

Comment: OK, I tested this.. I cannot use `@Autowired @Lazy` with Spring 3, but I can with Spring 4 - and it works perfectly. I also took the time to work out how to use `javax.inject.Inject` and `javax.inject.Provider` as [Tom's Blog](http://zezutom.blogspot.com.au/2014/01/spring-series-part-4-lazy-on-injection.html) described, but it just takes way too much extra code because I would have to write a `Provider` type for every single web driver because they are each different classes.

Comment: So, in conclusion, if I can move to Spring 4, `@Autowired @Lazy` does exactly what I want. If I have to stay with Spring 3, I am happy enough to keep using `appContext.getBean(..)` as a compromise. So, thanks @Biju!

Comment: Surprised that it doesn't work with Spring 3, can you provide the specific version of Spring that you used - 3.2.9?, I can also give it a test and let you know how it goes at my end.

Comment: It's at the bottom of my question. :) Spring 3.2.6.RELEASE